# How can I compile gVim under Ubuntu?

Tags: plugins, compilation, vim, vim-plugin

I am trying to install the [codecheck](http://code.google.com/p/codecheck/) plugin for gVim, but to do so I must compile gVim with the plugin.

On apt, every apt-get source to a gVim package downloads the normal Vim source, so I guess compiling the GUI must be a configure option. However, I can install the plugin on Vim but I can't compile gVim (since when I make there appears no gVim executable).

Any help compiling gVim?

Comment: Same on AskUbuntu: http://askubuntu.com/questions/132724/how-do-i-compile-the-latest-gvim-from-source

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm pretty sure you can just add `--enable-gui=gtk2` when `configure`ing. At least, that's how I remember doing it.

Answer (score 4):

1. `apt-get build-dep vim` to install the build dependencies for Vim.
2. Read `src/INSTALL`, as explained in the `README.txt` in the top-level directory of the source, to see how to configure and compile it.

Comment: It'd sure be keen if Martin could just drop his patch somewhere in the `debian/` directory, modify a file somewhere to mention the patch, and just run `dpkg-buildpackage` to build a replacement package. But I haven't got a clue where to put a patch or what file to modify to include the patch during the build...

Comment: Even better would be to use a plugin, like http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=2736, instead of trying to use an alpha quality patch to Vim's source.

Comment: The drawback with using the Debian/Ubuntu package is also that it is often behind the upstream patch level and/or may introduce changes that you do not want.
A daily/nightly build of current Vim (e.g. via some PPA) would be nice to have.

Comment: @blueyed: I specifically maintain a minimal delta between upstream Vim and Debian's packaging.  You can see the specific patches I apply at http://patch-tracker.debian.org/package/vim.  The package does lag behind upstream, but I watch the dev list and do try to stay on top of important patches.

Answer (score 2):

After you've got your dependencies installed and you can't find the gvim executable, then try `vim -g` from the terminal - that's the flag for starting in GUI mode. It's always worth a shot.

Comment: Yes, but it will only work if compiled originally with the GUI option.

Answer (score 1):

It seems this is a more updated version: http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Building_Vim